# How to show title of first list item in a script webpart with client side javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I am using O365. I have a list "SiteInformation". I would like to show the title of the first list item in a sript editor webpart. I would like to use client side javascript. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The "Site Information" list view web part and the title you want to show on the page? Or where exactly you want to place that script editor web part.

- If both are not in same page you can fetch using REST API call and display in a required format.
- If both web parts on same page then using JavaScript you can get first Item title and display on a container.

Let me know your approach will give you snippet.

Snippet to get your title. I am assuming you are using jQuery library in your site

`getSiteTitle = function(requestUrl, success, fail){
        $.ajax({
            url: requestUrl,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                success(data);

            },
            error: function (data) {
                fail(data);
            }
        });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('SiteInformation')?$top=1&$select=Title&$orderby=ID";
    getSiteTitle(url, function(data) {
        var title = "";
        var results = data.d.results;
        if(results != null && results.length > 0) {
            title = results[0].Title;
        }
        //logic to update title in your container
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Failed to load title");
    }
});`

Comment: No the SiteInformation list view webpart will not be on the same page as where I would like to show the title of the first list item. It will be a separated page.

Comment: Update my answer with code snippet

Answer (score 2):

The script should be something like this

```
var thaUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Alertas')/items?$top=1&$orderby ID&$select=Title";
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: thaUrl,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        body: {},
        success: function (data) {
            var results = data.d.results;
            //your script
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert('Solicitud fallida. ' + JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    });
```